# Find area of triangle ABC

Tags: triangles

BD Perpendicular AC , AB =BC=a

Find the area of triangle ABC

[image]

I have tried Googling , I used formula 1/2 (base X Height) . Used Pythagorean theorem. Anyone can suggest me solution.

Comment: perhaps i should say something more helpful, pythagoras theorem.

Comment: @Lost1, please let's be civil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y$ represent the distance $CD$. Then $y^2+x^2=a^2$, or $y=\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$.  Now you have enough to find the area of triangle $BCD$ using your area formula.  Double this to find the area of the whole triangle.

Comment: Found answer 2a.\sqrt{x^2-q^2}$.  Thanks man you guys so supportive

Answer (score 2):

With reference to comments: **Let's be supportive**.

If BD is a perpendicular, then you can split ABC into two right-angled triangles, so it is easier to work with:
[image]

Then you can use the formula $Area = \frac{1}{2}\cdot base \cdot height$ for each triangle, and add the two. You'll need to find the size of the base of each triangle using the pythagorean theorem.

Comment: I have found answer 2a. Sqrt of x^2-a^2